# google extension - intercepting ajax call stopped working suddenly

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension

everything was working flawlessly like 3 days ago when I finished writing some code and testing. Today when I wanted to do some more changes it stopped working.. Like without a reason. Code didn't change a bit. I'm getting this error:

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Debugger tells me that error has been thrown somewhere during this call:

`return open.apply(this, arguments);`

Because of that anything that should be loaded via AJAX on the site is not working.

This is the code for intercepting the AJAX calls:

```
var XHR = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;

var open = XHR.open;
var send = XHR.send;
var setRequestHeader = XHR.setRequestHeader;

XHR.open = function (method, url) {
    this._url = url;
    this._requestHeaders = {};

    return open.apply(this, arguments);
};

XHR.setRequestHeader = function (header, value) {
    this._requestHeaders[header] = value;
    return setRequestHeader.apply(this, arguments);
};

XHR.send = function (postData) {
    this.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var myUrl = this._url ? this._url.toLowerCase() : this._url;
        if (myUrl) {
            if (this.responseType != 'blob' && this.responseText) {
                try {
                    var allowedUrls = ['shoutbox.json', 'comments/latest.json'];

                    if (new RegExp(allowedUrls.join("|")).test(this._url)) {
                        var extensionID = 'exampleExtensionID';
                        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionID, { interception: true });
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return send.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Has anyone idea why it might stopped working?

Answer (score 0):

I had to put my injected.js (XHR) into self invoking function.